# QBasic/QB64: How to clean up an IF THEN IF "ladder"?

Tags: qbasic, qb64

Not sure if I'm using the right terms here, but for whatever reason, QBasic doesn't understand something along the lines of "x = y = z". It's limited to two.

To fix that, I did this:

```
IF sum(1) = sum(2) THEN
    IF sum(2) = sum(3) THEN
        IF sum(3) = sum2(1) THEN
            IF sum2(1) = sum2(2) THEN
                IF sum2(2) = sum2(3) THEN
                    IF sum2(3) = sum3 THEN
                        IF sum3 = sum4 THEN
                            PRINT "This is a Lo Shu Square, with all sums equaling"; sum(1)
                        ELSE
                            PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu Square."
                        END IF
                    END IF
                END IF
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF
END IF
END
```

Definitely works, but something tells me there's a simpler way to have it check if all of the sums equal the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: QBasic knows `AND`. And if _all_ values shall be the same, it is enough to compare all to one. E.g.: `IF sum(1) = sum(2) AND sum(1) = sum(3) AND ...` because A=B && A=C => B=C

Comment: QBasic does actually understand `x = y = z`.  That's comparing `x` with `z` and assigning the result to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

It would work if all comparisons where put on one line separated by AND like this:

```
REM code to shrink IFTHEN ladder:
IF sum(1) = sum(2) AND sum(2) = sum(3) AND sum(3) = sum2(1) AND sum2(1) = sum2(2) AND sum2(2) = sum2(3) AND sum2(3) = sum3 AND sum3 = sum4 THEN
    PRINT "This is a Lo Shu Square, with all sums equaling"; sum(1)
ELSE
    PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu Square."
END IF
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also code the logic into a loop:

```
DIM testvals(8)
testvals(0) = sum(1)
testvals(1) = sum(2)
testvals(2) = sum(3)
testvals(3) = sum2(1)
testvals(4) = sum2(2)
testvals(5) = sum2(3)
testvals(6) = sum3
testvals(7) = sum4
DO 
    FOR i = 1+LBOUND(testvals) TO UBOUND(testvals)
        IF testvals(i-1) <> testvals(i) THEN
            PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu square."
            EXIT DO
        END IF
    NEXT
    PRINT "This is a Lo Shu square, with all sums equaling"; sum(1)
LOOP WHILE 1 = 0
```

This has a couple of benefits:

1. It's easier to spot a typo if you change the code.
2. You can always add and remove test values in similar cases.  In this case, there's no need to do such a thing, but in some other cases, it may be beneficial to simply type `testvals(8) = value` and change the `8` to a `9` in the `DIM` line.
3. It short-circuits the comparison, meaning if the first condition is false, it stops checking and says it's not a Lo Shu Square, similar to a tower of `IF-THEN-ELSE` statements (where every `ELSE` is `PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu square."`)  QB64's `AND` operator evaluates both operands, even if the first operand is 0 or another "false" value.  This can be much faster, though you likely won't notice a difference in this case.

On the other hand, it does have some drawbacks:

1. It's an unusual pattern in QB64 to not use `AND` in a case like this.  In fact, this is one very good reason why `AND` exists.
2. You can just as easily remove test values that are combined using `AND` with no need to renumber the items in the `testvals` array or change its dimensions.
3. Even if you have many test values, it's often better to write a small program that generates the `IF a AND b AND c AND ... THEN ... END IF` block yourself (or something similar to your `IF-THEN` tower to retain short-circuit behavior) and paste the output into your program's code where it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to check arrays:

```
testvals(1) = sum(1)
testvals(2) = sum(2)
testvals(3) = sum(3)
testvals(4) = sum2(1)
testvals(5) = sum2(2)
testvals(6) = sum2(3)
testvals(7) = sum3
testvals(8) = sum4
FOR i = 1 TO 7
    IF testvals(i) <> testvals(i + 1) THEN
        f = -1
        EXIT FOR
    END IF
NEXT
IF f THEN
    PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu square."
ELSE
    PRINT "This is a Lo Shu square, with all sums equaling"; sum(1)
END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to check a loop:

```
testvals(1) = sum(1)
testvals(2) = sum(2)
testvals(3) = sum(3)
testvals(4) = sum2(1)
testvals(5) = sum2(2)
testvals(6) = sum2(3)
testvals(7) = sum3
testvals(8) = sum4
FOR i = 1 TO 7
    IF testvals(i) <> testvals(i + 1) THEN
        PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu square."
        END
    END IF
NEXT
PRINT "This is a Lo Shu square, with all sums equaling"; sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consolidate the logic into a function:

```
FUNCTION isLoShuSquare (sums() AS DOUBLE)

    isLoShuSquare = 1

    DIM i AS INTEGER
    FOR i = 0 TO UBOUND(sums) - 1
        IF sums(i) <> sums(i + 1) THEN
            isLoShuSquare = 0
            EXIT FOR
        END IF
    NEXT i

END FUNCTION
```

Then load the array and pass it to the function:

```
DIM sums(7) AS DOUBLE
DIM i AS INTEGER
i = 0
sums(i) = sum(1): i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum(2): i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum(3): i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum2(1): i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum2(2): i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum2(3): i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum3: i = i + 1
sums(i) = sum4

PRINT isLoShuSquare(sums())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check an array in a loop in a function:

```
DIM sums(8) AS DOUBLE
sums(1) = sum(1)
sums(2) = sum(2)
sums(3) = sum(3)
sums(4) = sum2(1)
sums(5) = sum2(2)
sums(6) = sum2(3)
sums(7) = sum3
sums(8) = sum4
IF isLoShuSquare(sums()) = 0 THEN
    PRINT "This is not a Lo Shu square."
ELSE
    PRINT "This is a Lo Shu square, with all sums equaling"; sum(1)
END IF
END
FUNCTION isLoShuSquare (sums() AS DOUBLE)
isLoShuSquare = -1
FOR i = 1 TO UBOUND(sums) - 1
    IF sums(i) <> sums(i + 1) THEN
        isLoShuSquare = 0
        EXIT FUNCTION
    END IF
NEXT
END FUNCTION
```